# Is there simpler (one-line) syntax to alias one class method?

Tags: ruby

I know I can do the following, and it's just 3 lines:

```
class << self
  alias :generate :new
end
```

But out of curiosity, is there a simpler way (without semicolons) like:

```
class_alias :generate, :new
```

Comment: Fun fact: `def self.generate; new; end` and `class_alias :generate, :new` are the same number of characters.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta That’s cheating, because `def self.generate; new; end` adds a redundant call on stack (not thta really matters, but to be as accurate as possible.)

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta It also doesn't work if you need `new` to take any arguments.

Comment: Surely an example of when 3 lines are better than 1 !

Comment: IMHO your 3 lines read better than the 1 line accepted answer.

Comment: The beauty of ruby is that its pretty easy to create your own dsl for anything. What's wrong with coding your `class_alias` I like it.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Since Ruby 1.9 you can use the `singleton_class` method to access the singleton object of a class. This way you can also access the `alias_method` method. The method itself is private so you need to invoke it with `send`. Here is your one liner:

```
singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :generate, :new)
```

Keep in mind though, that `alias` will not work here.

Comment: Small correction -- there is no need to prefix with `self.`

Comment: @jaustin Thanks! Didn't realize, after all it's defined on `Object`

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Beware: [alias and alias_method are not the same](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#alias-method-lexically)

Comment: That's neat!, thanks @KonradReiche
I was using this way
```
class << self
    alias_method :open, :new
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I am pasting some alias method examples

```
class Test
  def simple_method
    puts "I am inside 'simple_method' method"
  end

  def parameter_instance_method(param1)
    puts param1
  end

  def self.class_simple_method
    puts "I am inside 'class_simple_method'"
  end

  def self.parameter_class_method(arg)
    puts arg
  end


  alias_method :simple_method_new, :simple_method

  alias_method :parameter_instance_method_new, :parameter_instance_method

  singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :class_simple_method_new, :class_simple_method)
  singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :parameter_class_method_new, :parameter_class_method)
end

Test.new.simple_method_new
Test.new.parameter_instance_method_new("I am parameter_instance_method")

Test.class_simple_method_new
Test.parameter_class_method_new(" I am parameter_class_method")
```

> OUTPUT

```
I am inside 'simple_method' method
I am parameter_instance_method
I am inside 'class_simple_method'
I am parameter_class_method
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is any class-specific version of `alias`. I usually use it as you have previously demonstrated.

However you may want to [investigate the difference](http://andreacfm.com/2012/11/29/ruby-alias-vs-alias-method/) between `alias` and `alias_method`. This is one of those tricky areas of ruby that can be a bit counter-intuitive. In particular the behavior of `alias` with regard to descendants is probably not what you expect.

Hope this helps!